# Canonical question request: "Can I pay extra costs when casting a spell without paying its mana cost?"

Tags: support, questions, magic-the-gathering

We have a couple of questions that are just variations on the theme of paying additional costs on a spell being cast for free:

- [Hideaway Lands and Additional Costs](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31532/hideaway-lands-and-additional-costs)
- [Can an imprinted spell be kicked when it is cast?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28684/can-an-imprinted-spell-be-kicked-when-it-is-cast)

I'm not aware of a canonical question on the matter, but we should probably have one, either via editing or just wholly creating one. Could someone look into how we might do that?

I'm about to go to sleep and shouldn't be attempting this endeavour myself, but might attempt it if no action's been taken in the intervening time.